# How to fit to sum of observations?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, terminology, scikit-learn, software

From a practical point of view, how does one go about fitting a model to training data that consists of sums of a dependent variable over multiple conditions? For example, fitting a model to predict the incomes of individuals given only the incomes of households and the descriptors of each member of each household.

To be more precise: I wish to predict a dependent variable $y$ in from $n$ independent variables described by a vector $\vec{x}$. My training data does not consist of the usual sort of observations $(\vec{x}_i,y_i)$. Rather, I have the sums of various mutually exclusive subsets of ${y_i}$. In other words, my training data consists of $\{\vec{x}_i\}$ and $\{Y_k\}$, where

$$Y_k=\sum_{i\in{J_k}}{y_i}$$

The values of $\{J_k\}$ are known and are mutually exclusive, meaning that each $i$ is contained in one and only one $J_k$.

I would like to train a model $f(\vec{x})$ with this data using off-the-shelf tools. For example, using scikit-learn to fit a random forest regression. It's not clear to me how to do this through the API, which seems to require the training data to contain observations $(\vec{x}_i,y_i)$.

Also, what is the best terminology to describe this sort of optimization problem? Is there a specific name for it?

Comment: Do you wish to predict values for $y_i$or for $Y_k$? The former is problematic because you have no good estimation of the variance of $y_i$. Therefore I am not sure you can get useful estimates of $y_i$. You can train a model to this model, but I have severe doubts about it's usefullness, therefore I am reluctant to advise any method specifically,

Comment: You should first try to figure out if the $Y_k$'s are really different enough. For example if $J_k$ is large and the $Y_k$'s are similar and so are the $x_i$'s (even though they might have huge variance within the set)  no real analysis can be done

Comment: I am confident that there is sufficient variation in the values of $Y_k$ and $x_i$ in my dataset to produce a useful model. For example, I've found that linear models give reasonable results. (A linear model can be readily fitted using standard methods by treating each $Y_k$ as a single observation; the problem is how to fit a non-linear model.)

Comment: One thing that's clear is that this can only work if the expectation of $y_i$ given $x_i$ is independent of household.  If, for example, the characteristics or incomes of a household's OTHER members affect the expectation for $y_i$, then the problem gets devilishly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted in your comment, if your model is $y_i = w' x_i + e_i$, it implies that $Y_i = \sum_i y_i = w' \sum_i x_i + \sum_i e_i$ and performing a least squares fit of $Y_i$ from the sum of the input groups $\sum x_i$ would work well.

This can be generalized in a straightforward way to non-linear models where $y_i = w' \phi(x_i) + e_i$, where you can view $\phi(x_i)$ is a high-dimensional (kernel) expansion of $x_i$. Then $Y_i = w_i \sum_i \phi(x_i) + \sum_i e_i$.

Now if $K(x_i, x_j) = \phi(x_i)' \phi(x_j)$ is a given kernel function over your input space, the kernel function $K_s(\sum_i \phi(x_i), \sum_i \phi(x_j) = \sum_i \sum_j K(x_i, x_j)$.

Therefore a least squares solution using a given p.s.d. kernel function over your input space, can be done using your aggregate samples by constructing the sum kernel $K_s$ over your example sets $\{x_i\}$ and building a kernel regressor (least-squares SVM, say) to $Y_i$ and then using the solution weight vector with the original kernel $K$ to predict $y_i$.

This is all speculative, and I have no guarantees for how well it works for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is an iterative approach.

In Step 1, you assume that each y_i contributes to Y_k equally, and do the fit. You'll get a way of predicting y using x.

Now in Step 2, you use your predictions for y_i from Step 1, normalized so they still add up to Y_k. You'll get a different model to predict y using x.

Repeat the steps until your predictions converge/plateau.

I think you can set this up with most standard tools.